# Finding custom feature usage

Tags: custom, features

How do I find which custom feature (50+) is installed and activated in which subsite (1000+ sub sites) in a SharePoint 2010 site.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PowerShell Script To Find Where SharePoint 2010 Features Are Activated](http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2012/07/02/powershell-script-to-find-where-sharepoint-2010-features-are-activated.aspx)

```
function Get-SPFeatureActivated 
{ 
# see full script for help info, removed for formatting 
[CmdletBinding()] 
param( 
  [Parameter(position = 1, valueFromPipeline=$true)] 
  [Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPFeatureDefinitionPipeBind] 
  $Identity 
)#end param 
  Begin 
  { 
    # declare empty array to hold results. Will add custom member ` 
    # for Url to show where activated at on objects returned from Get-SPFeature. 
    $results = @() 

    $params = @{} 
  } 
  Process 
  { 
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Identity) -eq $false) 
    { 
      $params = @{Identity = $Identity 
            ErrorAction = "SilentlyContinue" 
      } 
    } 

    # check farm features 
    $results += (Get-SPFeature -Farm -Limit All @params | 
             % {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType noteproperty ` 
                -Name Url -Value ([string]::Empty) -PassThru} | 
             Select-Object -Property Scope, DisplayName, Id, Url) 

    # check web application features 
    foreach($webApp in (Get-SPWebApplication)) 
    { 
      $results += (Get-SPFeature -WebApplication $webApp -Limit All @params | 
               % {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType noteproperty ` 
                  -Name Url -Value $webApp.Url -PassThru} | 
               Select-Object -Property Scope, DisplayName, Id, Url) 

      # check site collection features in current web app 
      foreach($site in ($webApp.Sites)) 
      { 
        $results += (Get-SPFeature -Site $site -Limit All @params | 
                 % {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType noteproperty ` 
                    -Name Url -Value $site.Url -PassThru} | 
                 Select-Object -Property Scope, DisplayName, Id, Url) 

        $site.Dispose() 

        # check site features in current site collection 
        foreach($web in ($site.AllWebs)) 
        { 
          $results += (Get-SPFeature -Web $web -Limit All @params | 
                   % {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType noteproperty ` 
                      -Name Url -Value $web.Url -PassThru} | 
                   Select-Object -Property Scope, DisplayName, Id, Url) 

          $web.Dispose() 
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  End 
  { 
    $results 
  } 
} #end Get-SPFeatureActivated
```

Then filter for only custom features

Comment: Please provide the details from the link. If the link goes down the answer will not be useful